# How to get ViewHolder of items of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design

I'm working on a RecyclerView and I want to add a parallax effect to my images on cards. If I use ParallaxEveryWhere library it works fine but I want to create it manually.

Now the problem is that I want to get ViewHolder of all items out of my adapter. I have tried all RecyclerView methods to get Viewholder of an item but all of them have returned null.

**I'm looking for a solution to get ViewHolder of Items in RecyclerView out of it's adapter**

Comment: Your question is not clear, please be a bit more clear.

Comment: You can use a custom interface inside the adapter and implement it in your activity . That's the only way you can get the viewHolder's members .

Comment: can you please give out some code ?

Comment: any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the Skeleton of RecyclerView

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    public YourAdapter( Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_item, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

         viewHolder.textView.setText("Text");
         viewHolder.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView textView;
        public ImageView imgView;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            imgView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);

        }

    }

}
```

For Example if you have TextView and ImageView as Items in your ViewHolder, you can access those items in `onBindViewHolder()` method

Comment: I told you **out of the Adapter**

Answer (score 0):

In above code there is return 0,so that it will return 0,
put some value there so adapter return some value.

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private Context context;
        public YourAdapter( Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.card_item, viewGroup, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

             viewHolder.textView.setText("Text");
             viewHolder.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return imgView.length;
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

            public TextView textView;
            public ImageView imgView;
            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                imgView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);

            }

        }

    }
```

i wish your problem will soved with this..